# Where do Abadon Crusher Mutants spawn on the surface of the world?

Tags: achievements, rage-2

In Rage 2 the Crusher achievement requires you to kill an Abadon Crusher Mutant with your Pheonix vehicle. As far as I can tell the only location where Abadon Crusher Mutants spawn and are still accessible with the Phoenix is at "D and D's Hood" in The Wilds region. Unfortunately, I killed these two massive mutants before I knew of the achievement.

Since "Digg the Smasher" and "Dugg the Basher" are already dead and I don't have a saved game where they are still alive I do not seem able to earn this achievement. Are there any other locations where Abadon Crusher Mutants will spawn and I can kill with my Phoenix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [guide](https://www.trueachievements.com/a274122/crushed-achievement) for this achievement.

The answer is **yes**, there are a few random spawn locations where Abadon Crusher Mutants may spawn.

> The first location is in southeast of the town 'Gunbarrel' in a meteorite craters. The second random spawn location is in the southwest of the town 'Wellspring'.
>   I found (later) a third random spawn location. Directly above from the first MBTV location in Broken Tract.